Unable to generate serenity summmery report in gradle
I am attempting to generate a Serenity summary report for publishing in an Azure DevOps pipeline.
I am able to generate a single-page report, but I am encountering difficulty in generating the summary report.
Below is my configuration:
build.gradle
plugins {
  id 'net.serenity-bdd.serenity-gradle-plugin' version '3.9.8'
}

---------------------------
 testImplementation("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenityVersion}")
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-spring:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-ensure:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-single-page-report:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:${serenityVersion}") {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-xml'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-json'
    }
    testImplementation "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine"
--------------------------------
tasks.named('integrationTest') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy 'aggregate'
}
-------------------------------------
gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true

serenity {
    reports = ["single-page-html"]
}

I am getting below error.
> Task :aggregate
Generating Serenity Reports
  - Test Root: target/site/serenity
  - Main report: file:///C:/workspace/eod/target/site/serenity/index.html
      - Test Root: target/site/serenity
      - Requirements base directory: null
> Task :reports
Generating Additional Serenity Reports for eod to directory C:\workspace\eod\target\site\serenity
No report found on classpath with name single-page-html

serenity reports are generatiing under target directory. How to move it build directory?
